# Relating two fact tables with many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, powerbi, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I have two fact tables as part of my data model:

FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS
-where one order can relate to many equipment pieces

FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS
-where one equipment can have many equipment descriptions

Is there a way to relate order with equipment descriptions (for filtering orders), without creating a brand new table? (Ultimately it would be possible to create a new fact table if there is no better way)

Comment: Do you mean that the "orders" fact table has an ID for equipment, but then there are multiple instances of that equipment ID in the "descriptions" table?  And is it that the different descriptions are perhaps date/time based?

Comment: If you want to combine data from multiple fact tables then you need to query each fact table independently and then combine the resultsets (e.g. using CTEs, UNIONs, etc). In general, you should never join fact tables in the same query

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can relate the orders in FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS with the equipment descriptions in FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS without creating a new table by utilizing bridge tables or using a combination of existing tables.

One approach is to create a bridge table that establishes a many-to-many relationship between orders and equipment descriptions. This bridge table would contain the primary keys from FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS and FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS. Each row in the bridge table represents a specific combination of an order and an equipment description.

This is how the bridge table could be structured:

BRIDGE_TABLE_ORDER_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS

- Order_ID (foreign key referencing FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS)
- Equipment_Description_ID (foreign key referencing FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS)

By joining the bridge table with FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS and FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS on their respective primary keys, you can relate orders with equipment descriptions. This allows you to filter orders based on equipment descriptions.

Another approach is to utilize existing tables and create intermediate joins. Assuming FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS already has a foreign key to FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS, you can directly join the two tables without the need for a bridge table. Here's an example:

SELECT *
FROM FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS
JOIN FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS ON FACT_TABLE_A_ORDERS.Equipment_Description_ID = FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS.Equipment_Description_ID
WHERE FACT_TABLE_B_EQUIPMENT_DESCRIPTIONS.Description = 'desired description';

In this query, you can filter orders based on the desired equipment description. Adjust the WHERE clause to match your specific filtering criteria.

Comment: Copy-paste from ChatGPT

Comment: Joining fact to fact is not really recommended. Like the idea of a bridge table though..